# Reformatting a tab in vim

Tags: indentation, formatting

I am new to vim, and I'm facing an interesting problem. I need to reformat a file so that the indentation is consistent. How do I do this?

Comment: Edited @Jake Grossman

Comment: @Rich typo. I can't edit it now

Comment: Can you describe "consistent indentation"? It could mean a number of different things.

Comment: @TheMaskedRebel you can click [edit] to edit. (Welcome to [vi.se]!)